# Lua Key name or auto-indexed?

Tags: c, loops, lua, indexing, lua-table

Assume the following two tables:

```
foo = {
  "aaa",
  "bbb",
  "ccc"
}

bar = {
  first  = "aaa",
  second = "bbb",
  third  = "ccc"
}
```

Table `foo` have no keys assigned while `bar` has keys.
When I iterate the table `bar` I get the assigned key name and since it is a string it is easy to tell that these keys were defined in the Lua script.

But when I iterate `foo` I will, of course, get an integer as key, starting at 1. How can I see (or is it even possible) that this is an "auto-index" key and not defined in the table?

I'm traversing the table from C with `lua_next()` and checking type with `lua_type()`

I need to write back the table (as a Lua script) exactly the same way it was structured, meaning that if there wasn't a key to begin with (as in `foo`) I shall not write the numerical "auto-index", only the values.

**EDIT**
Maybe it wasn't that clear. The short version would be:

> is possible to distinguish between a numerical index set by the user/programmer
>   and one auto assigned by the Lua Engine?

Comment: You are conflating the concepts of "table constructor" (source code) and "table" (a runtime value). The information you seek is "compiled away." Surely, the user must come to understand the same distinctions.

Comment: It is a third party application reading the Lua file and if the tables aren't organized exactly as they where it will crash (not in my control). To make it more exciting, the table structures isn't consistent. Some tables have indexes, some don't. But I have it confirmed now, I need to extend the Lua compiler to make this information available.

Answer (score 3):

There are no such value that has no key in every table. The two tables in your example are just two styles of syntax sugar of table constructor.

```
foo = {
  "aaa",
  "bbb",
  "ccc"
}
```

is just syntax sugar for:

```
foo = {
  [1] = "aaa",
  [2] = "bbb",
  [3] = "ccc"
}
```

And

```
bar = {
  first  = "aaa",
  second = "bbb",
  third  = "ccc"
}
```

is syntax sugar for:

```
bar = {
  ["first"]  = "aaa",
  ["second"] = "bbb",
  ["third"]  = "ccc"
}
```

The two styles can even be mixed, like:

```
foobar = {
  "aaa",
  first  = "aaa",
  "bbb",
  second = "bbb",
  "ccc",
  third  = "ccc"
}
```

Again, every value has a key, it's just integers from `1` in the case of `foo`, and strings in the case of `bar`.

Comment: Yes, I know all this and the question was if it is possible to distinguish between a numerical index set by the user and one auto assigned by the Lua Engine. Maybee my question was that clear.

Comment: No, only the parser knows (before it's converted to bytecode), and it does not tell.

Answer (score 1):

The first one, `foo`, is equivalent to

```
foo = {
    1 = "aaa",
    2 = "bbb",
    3 = "ccc"
}
```

[No it's not valid Lua, but it's the principle I'm after.]

In this case the index *is* the key.

Comment: Yes, I know this and the question was if it is possible to distinguish between a numerical index set by the user and one auto assigned by the Lua Engine. I guess there is no way to tell the difference.